# Unlink images, remove unclosed p's and remove all styles

Tags: php, html, html-parsing, domdocument

I have some problems with my Wordpress posts and I'm trying to use DOMDocument to fix them.

The first problem is that my images (`<img>` are inside an `<a>` tag and I want to remove the `<a>` tags.

I also want to remove all unclosed `<p>` tags (which don't have a `</p>`) and I want to remove the `style` from all elements.

I can post some code I've tried, but I don't think it would help at all, because I got nowhere with it. I've only tried removing links from images for now, but nothing seems to work. I don't really understand how to work with DOMDocument child elements very well.

Here you can see an HTML example that needs fixing:

```
<img width="750" height="500" src="http://fancycribs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Modern-Riverside-Apartment-–-A-Stylish-and-Elegant-Residence-6.jpg" class="attachment-large wp-post-image" alt="Modern Riverside Apartment – A Stylish and Elegant Residence (6)" />        <p>This modern seventh floor riverside apartment is placed in the luxurious and modern Montevetro Building, which is close to Battersea Square with access to Chelsea, Fulham and Kings Road by crossing Battersea Bridge, London. This residence has become one of the iconic buildings in the Battersea area.</p>
<p>It offers spectacular views over the serene tranquility of the river. This apartment offers comfort and luxury throughout its double reception room, three bedrooms, three bathrooms and large decked balcony. The design details are astonishing: mahogany wood floors, original hand painted walls, large floor to ceiling windows offering a spectacular view over the river. The apartment is spacious, the space between living room and dining room is fluid, having continuity. The hall is large and has a lot of storage spaces, having the quality to link rooms one to another. The kitchen space is large and has plenty of storage capacity. It is dressed up in mahogany wood, offering personality and contrast and access to the large balcony.</p>
<p>The master bedroom is a masterpiece of style and elegance, with nice and simple furniture, a bathroom and accompanied by two further double bedrooms, a family bathroom and a shower room. The residence overwhelms you through its luxury and the splendid view.</p>
<p style="text-align: center"><a href="http://fancycribs.com/37216-modern-riverside-apartment-a-stylish-and-elegant-residence.html/modern-riverside-apartment-a-stylish-and-elegant-residence-7" rel="attachment wp-att-39033" class="local-link"><img class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-39033" alt="Modern Riverside Apartment – A Stylish and Elegant Residence" src="http://fancycribs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Modern-Riverside-Apartment-–-A-Stylish-and-Elegant-Residence-7-670x446.jpg" width="670" height="446" title="Modern Riverside Apartment – A Stylish and Elegant Residence" /></a></p>
<p style="text-align: center">
```

Later edit:

Here's what I tried and it seems to unlink the images, but only the image number 1,3,5,7, while 2,4,6 remain unchanged.

```
$html = new DOMDocument;
$html->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$html->loadHTML('<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">'.$content);
foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a) {
    if($a->hasChildNodes()) {
        $img = $a->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0);
        $a->parentNode->replaceChild($img,$a);
    }
}
$text = $html->saveHTML();
echo $text;
```

Thank you

Comment: if your html is mangled, then use htmlpurifier to TRY and clean it up. PHP's dom is **EXTREMELY** picky and will at best puke/barf all of your html, or mangle it even worse.  Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: I didn't know about that, thanks. I will try it for the unclosed <p> tags. But I still have to unlink the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do it with DOMDocument and HTML Purifier.

Here's the code:

```
require_once 'library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.TidyLevel','heavy');
$config->set('AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty','true');
$config->set('AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty.RemoveNbsp','true');
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

$clean_html = $purifier->purify($content);
$html = new DOMDocument;
$html->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$html->loadHTML('<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">'.$clean_html);
$as = $html->getElementsByTagName('a');
$ctr = $html->getElementsByTagName('a')->length;
for($i=$ctr;$i>0;--$i) {
    $a = $html->getElementsByTagName('a')->item($i-1);
    if($a->hasChildNodes()) {
        $img = $a->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0);
        if($img != null) {
            $a->parentNode->replaceChild($img,$a);
        }
    }
}

foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('p') as $p) {
    $p->removeAttribute('style');
}
$text = $html->saveHTML();
echo $text;
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to run this code and see if you are satisfied. This finds `<a ...><img ... and replaces it to just <img ...`

```
$p = "/<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*<img.*)<\/a>/siU";
$newHtml = preg_replace($p, '$3', $html , PREG_SET_ORDER );
```

Comment: I don't want to use regex for HTML.